# GlassFish Server 4.0 start error with JDK

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, java, glassfish-4

I'm using NetBeans 7.3.1 with GlassFish Server 4

When I try to run a(any) project I get the following error.

Starting GlassFish Server
GlassFish Server Server start failed. Cant create start proccess.
C:\Users\ENES\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Tezmaksan\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1041: Deployment error: GlassFish Server Server start failed. Cant create start proccess.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

I don't know where the log file is, I couldn't find it.

When I go bin directory of GlassFish and run startserv.bat, it looks like working because localhost:8080/ and localhost:4848/ are working. But my application still can't start.
When I go localhost:8080/Tezmaksan/ there is this error there

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

I have last verison of JDK (1.7u25) installed and when I check from NetBeans it is selected for GlassFish. I'm using x64 Windows 7. I didn't have this problem 2-3 months ago, it just popped out. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling NetBeans, GlassFish and JDK and problem is still there.

Thanks for your helps

Comment: check glassfish logs and post full stack trace in your post.

Comment: [Tyr this once][1]


[similar][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17556533/2396513
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555894/org-apache-jasper-jasperexception-pwc6345-there-is-an-error-in-invoking-javac


try to make the env with jdk jre

Comment: @RafaelOsipov where can I find that log file?

Comment: @Siva it is set to JDK and tried other things at that post, didn't help

Comment: @enesfarukmeniz Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/13836744/784540

Comment: @RafaelOsipov what if there aren't any logs? I cleared log file folder then re-run netbeans, run the application same error but no log file is created

Comment: @enesfarukmeniz I do not recall the exact path, but check your local user folder. `C:\Users\%yourusername%\`. There are also folders related to installed apps, but containing information related to a specific user. And make sure that you have met [GlassFish installation prerequisites](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2434/abpaj.html)

Comment: Ok now this is weird. I did some things(not sure what exactly) and now when I run "asadmin start-domain" it works then I can deploy applications from NetBeans. But I still can not start GlassFish from NetBeans, I have to run it myself from console (cmd.exe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution after searching through the web.
Adding an option to a NetBeans setting file will do it.

Open NETBEANS_DIRECTORY/etc/netbeans.conf

Search for "netbeans_default_options"
Then add "--locale en"

So it will look like from this

netbeans_default_options="-J-client...

to this

netbeans_default_options="--locale en -J-client...

restart NetBeans, problem solved.