# Xplanner not deploy on Payara/Glassfish server

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

I had this error when trying to deploy xplanner-plus in payara (glassfish),
I have all the applications I work with, but when I try to deploy xplanner-plus, this happens. In another pc with the same payara has gone well. But I need to deploy it on my pc.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve@7744dad3: Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=javax.servlet.ServletException, location=/WEB-INF/jsp/common/unexpectedError.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac." error when using Jetty WTP plugin to deploy a JSP page on Jetty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113346/pwc6345-there-is-an-error-in-invoking-javac-error-when-using-jetty-wtp-plugi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac. A full JDK (not just JRE) is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555894/org-apache-jasper-jasperexception-pwc6345-there-is-an-error-in-invoking-javac)

Comment: If not a duplicate of the question in the first flag, probably a duplicate of one of the few listed in the second flag

Comment: The issue is that none of the duplicate questions give a convincing answer because I only happen with the xplanner paling. With other applications it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run Payara Server with [Java JDK edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), not with JRE. Some functionality in GlassFish/Payara is available only with JDK.

In your case, compiling JSPs requires Java compiler (javac) in the Java installation. You could avoid this exception if you precompiled all JSPs during build time (e.g. with a maven plugin).