# Writing first Liferay application: how to deploy module to server + error: A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-ide

I'm following Liferay getting-started [example](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018157411-Writing-Your-First-Liferay-DXP-Application-) to develop my first we app with Liferay IDE in which it is mentioned:

> Even though all you’ve done is generate it, the `guestbook-web` project is ready to be built and deployed to Liferay DXP. Make sure that your server is running, and if it isn’t, select it in Developer Studio’s Servers pane and click the start button. After it starts, **drag and drop** the `guestbook-web` project from the Project Explorer to the server.

I started the server, however, I don't know how to deploy `guestbook-web` module to server. Drag and drop is *not* working for me:

[image: Liferay IDE Screenshot]

When Opening the web page, this is shown which doesn't contain anything related to `guestbook-web` module:

[image: Web page screenshot]

---

#### Update

When I drag and drop my module on server, for some reason it is *not* allowed:

[image: Drag and drop is forbidden]

---

#### Update

Also, I'm receiving such errors on console:

```
22-Apr-2020 16:02:54.419 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Module Framework Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required] with root cause
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
```

I have set both JDK and JRE path for IDE, not sure why it says `A full JDK (not just JRE) is required`.

---

#### Update

To fix `A full JDK (not just JRE) is required` error, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17565232/3405291), I ran the IDE with this command:

```sh
C:\Program Files (x86)\LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudioCommunityEdition\liferay-developer-studio>DeveloperStudio.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\javaw.exe"
```

The error is resolved and default widgets are fine now:

[image: Widgets are fine now]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the IDE: You'll drag the "guestbook-web" with the mouse and drop it right *on* the highlighted "Liferay 7.x at localhost" Server (Note: *on*, *not below*).

Outside of the IDE: Your project generates a jar, and you can copy that to Liferay's `deploy` directory.

Once the module is deployed, it won't magically show up on the page: Log in as Administrator, choose the "Add" button (a plus sign) and add a "widget" to the page: In the list of Widgets you'll find your new portlet/widget.

The screenshot of your installation looks weird though, as if something didn't go wrong and you'll likely need to look for signs of problems in the log file to see why Liferay ends up in the state that it's in, with a couple of default widgets being unavailable - however, that's unrelated to the question how to deploy new code to the runtime.

**Edit:** You've mentioned the required JDK from the log. That's good to be fixed.

With regards to the not-working drag&drop: It looks like you're using Liferay Workspace. From the icons in Project Explorer, it looks like your module isn't recognized as such: Try to "Gradle/Refresh Gradle Project" (right-click on "modules") to see if it needs some updates that are missing (and observe its log output). Icons on my IDE look like this:

[image: illustration for module icons]

Once you get those modules recognized, you should be able to drag&drop them to the server.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the post with a screenshot of drag and drop =)

Comment: Also updated my post with console log errors: `A full JDK (not just JRE) is required`

Comment: Sounds like the result to _"you'll likely need to look for signs of problems in the log file"_

Comment: Right =) I'm not sure why drag-and-drop is still *not* working for me :(

Comment: I missed that drag&drop problem earlier. See my edits. Thanks for accepting the answer already.

Answer (score 0):

I realized to avoid `A full JDK (not just JRE) is required` error, it is needed to setup server correctly while creating it with GUI:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Step 5]

[image: Step 6]

[image: Step 7]